# How to store a command to a variable in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, grep

I am trying to execute the following command in a Bash script:

```
grep 1001 -w /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 1,4,5
grep 1004 -w /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 1,4,5
```

it works fine from the command line in Linux, and if I remove the latter portion of the pipeline it executes properly from Bash as well.

here is my script thus far:

```
#/bin/bash

#find the group number correlated to reader and user
reader=`grep reader /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f3`
user=`grep user /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f3`

echo reader: $reader #prints 1004
echo user: $user #prints 1001

cmdRead="grep ${reader} -w /etc/passwd | cut -d \":\" -f 1,4,5"
cmdUser="grep ${user} -w /etc/passwd | cut -d \":\" -f 1,4,5"

echo executing command: ${cmdRead}
echo `${cmdRead}`
echo executing command: ${cmdUser}
echo `${cmdUser}`
```

the output of this code yields:

```
reader: 1004
user: 1001
executing command: grep 1004 -w /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f 1,4,5
grep: invalid argument ‘":"’ for ‘--directories’
Valid arguments are:
  - ‘read’
  - ‘recurse’
  - ‘skip’
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.

executing command: grep 1001 -w /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f 1,4,5
grep: invalid argument ‘":"’ for ‘--directories’
Valid arguments are:
  - ‘read’
  - ‘recurse’
  - ‘skip’
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

I only started learning Bash yesterday so I apologize for the noob-esque question but greatly appreciate any help :)

Comment: Enclose your command in `$( ... )`, not quotes:  `cmdRead=$(grep ${reader} -w /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f 1,4,5)`.

Comment: Also, no need to quote the colon as the value of the -f parameter in `cut`, therefore no need to escape the quotes. See my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks so much @AndrewVickers am I able to mark your comment as an accepted answer?

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: @CyberStems I added an answer below so you can accept/up-vote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose your command in `$( ... )`, not quotes. Also, no need to quote the colon as the value of the -f parameter in cut, therefore no need to escape the quotes:

```
cmdRead=$(grep ${reader} -w /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f 1,4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

@AndrewVickers has answered the question in the comments, below is his answer copy/pasted

> Enclose your command in `$( ... )`, not quotes: `cmdRead=$(grep ${reader} -w /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f 1,4,5)`
>
> Also, no need to quote the colon as the value of the -f parameter in `cut`, therefore no need to escape the quotes.